# Moving VBA/SQL procedure from Access to Excel / PowerQuery

Tags: sql, excel, vba, powerbi

I have a rather lengthy vba procedure which I built in Access and I am trying to adapt to Excel. Basically my boss doesn't use Access so I have to deliver something that works in Excel.

I have been playing around with Power Query and Power Pivot and am hoping that I can use these to create an Excel solution.

The procedure for calculating monthly interest accruals. It cycles through records in the parent table and based on criteria builds an executes a INSERT INTO SQL statement to create new records from the calculation into a child table.

I have been reading forums and watching youtube vids, but am missing how to achieve this conceptually.

Can anyone point me to a good place to start? I have only really had a little  MSAccess SQL and VBA coding experience, with no formal education; just picked things up on forums etc.

I can put the all the code up if necessary but it is long.
I think I just need help in getting the values into and out of the code

```vb
'1.1 Set Database and Recordset - where the data is coming from
Dim thisDB As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set thisDB = CurrentDb()
Set rs = thisDB.OpenRecordset("tblInvestments")
```

....

```vb
'2.1 Start Loop to check records in the recordset [tblInvestments]
Do While Not rs.EOF
            AccountID = rs!AccountID
            InvestmentID = rs!InvestmentID
            iType = rs!Type
            Interest = rs!Interest
            Principal = rs!Principal
            iRate = rs!Rate
            CommenceDate = rs!Commence
            MatureDate = rs!Mature
            ParentUpdate = rs!LastUpdateDate
```

&...

```vb
 '5.5 Build SQL Query and append to table

        StrSQL = "INSERT INTO tblInterestRevenue ( InvestmentID, InterestDate, PrincipalDebit, PrincipalCredit, PeriodInterest, AccumulatedInterest, PeriodPaidInterest) "
        StrSQL = StrSQL & "VALUES (" & InvestmentID & ",#" & InterestDate & "#," & PrincipalDebit & "," & PrincipalCredit & "," & PeriodInterest & "," & AccumInterest & "," & PeriodInterestPaid & ")"

        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL StrSQL
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

Thanks Heaps,
Dom

Comment: A Power Pivot model needs to get its data from somewhere when you Rerfresh it. Can't you just read the data from tblInterestRevenue into your model? Also looping through rows in your VBA is probably unnecessary. You could try to re-write it as one piece of SQL and use the SQL as the data source for your model.

Comment: I am hoping that tblInterestRevenue will hold the data and feed into PowerPivot for reporting, but the VBA code in Access wrote / populated tblInterestRevenue from data in tblInvestments (i.e. the parent table). I am not quite sure what you mean by "re-write it as one piece of SQL and use the SQL as the data source for your model". I think that if I can get the values from tblInvestments into my VBA variables then I might be able to use the .ListRows.Add method to populate tblInterestRevenue. I am open to any feedback / suggestions.

Comment: Are you happy with the data you're putting into tblInterestRevenue? If so just read both tables into PowerPivot via Get Data. You want the resulting Power Query to be Connection Only so it loads directly to the power pivot model, not into a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```vb
'1.1 Get Data from tblInvestments
Dim tblInvestments As ListObject
Dim x As Long
Set tblInvestments = Sheets("Investments").ListObjects("tblInvestments")
'Create Array List from Table
  arrInvestments = tblInvestments.DataBodyRange
```

...

```vb
'2.1 Start Loop to check records in the tblInvestments
'Loop Through Each DataBody Row in Table
 For x = 1 To tblInvestments.ListRows.Count
        InvestmentID = arrInvestments(x, 1)
        AccountID = arrInvestments(x, 2)
        iType = arrInvestments(x, 3)
        interest = arrInvestments(x, 4)
        Principal = arrInvestments(x, 7)
        iRate = arrInvestments(x, 8)
        CommenceDate = arrInvestments(x, 9)
        MatureDate = arrInvestments(x, 10)
        ParentUpdate = arrInvestments(x, 14)
```

...

```vb
'5.5 Append to table
        Lastrow = Sheets("Interest").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        With Sheets("Interest")
            .Cells(Lastrow, 1).Value = y
            .Cells(Lastrow, 2).Value = InvestmentID
            .Cells(Lastrow, 3).Value = InterestDate
            .Cells(Lastrow, 4).Value = PrincipalDebit
            .Cells(Lastrow, 5).Value = PrincipalCredit
            .Cells(Lastrow, 6).Value = PeriodInterest
            .Cells(Lastrow, 8).Value = AccumInterest
            .Cells(Lastrow, 10).Value = PeriodInterestPaid
        End With
```

Comment: You can simplify the entire `With` block to `Sheets("Interest").Range("A" & Lastrow & ':J" & Lastrow).Value = Array(y, InvestmentID, InterestDate, PrincipalDebit, PrincipalCredit, PeriodInterest, AccumInterest, PeriodInterestPaid)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I am not pasteing values into columns 7 or 9 - how can I achieve this with an array?

Comment: You can use `Empty` for the cells you want to leave empty -- `Array(y, InvestmentID, InterestDate, PrincipalDebit, PrincipalCredit, PeriodInterest,Empty, AccumInterest, Empty, PeriodInterestPaid)`